# CUDA: string comparison

Tags: string, cuda, comparison

I write a simple code about string comparison. The code is shown as follows.
It is very simple. Just compare string a and string b,if the corresponding elements are 
 same, then assign 5 to the new matrix s; if the corresponding elements are different, then 
assign -3 to the new matrix s.There is no compilation error. But the result is not what 
I expected.Please give me some useful suggestion. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "book.h"
#define M 6
#define BLOCK_SIZE 30 // maximum 1024 threads per block
#define GRID_SIZE 30 // 900 blocks per grid
#define P (900 * 900)

void Init();


char *gpu_a;
char *gpu_b;
float *gpu_s;
float *cpu_s;


char cpu_a[6] = {'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
char cpu_b[6] = {'G', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'G'};

void cpu_Allocate1dArray()
{
   //cpu_a = (char*) malloc( M * sizeof( char) );
   //cpu_b = (char*) malloc( M * sizeof(char) );
   cpu_s = (float*) malloc( M * sizeof( float) );
}

void gpu_Allocate1dArray()
{
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&gpu_a, M * sizeof(char) );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&gpu_b, M * sizeof(char) );
cudaMalloc( (void**)&gpu_s, M * sizeof(float));
}


__global__ void mykernel( char *gpu_a, char *gpu_b, float *gpu_s)
{
    int i , j , tid;
    i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    tid = i + j * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    if ( tid  < P)
{
       if( gpu_a[i] == gpu_b[j])
        {
      gpu_s[tid] = 5;
    }
       else
    gpu_s[tid] = -3;
    }         
}


int main()
{
   int q;
   cpu_Allocate1dArray();
   gpu_Allocate1dArray();

   Init();

   dim3 gridDim;
   dim3 blockDim;

   blockDim.x = blockDim.y = BLOCK_SIZE;
   gridDim.x = gridDim.y = GRID_SIZE;

   cudaMemcpy( gpu_a, cpu_a, sizeof(char) * M, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy( gpu_b, cpu_b, sizeof(char) * M, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   mykernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(gpu_a, gpu_b, gpu_s);
   cudaMemcpy( cpu_s, gpu_s, sizeof(float)* M, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   for (q = 0; q < M; q++)
       printf("%f ", cpu_s[q]);


   printf("\n");    

    //Free device memory

    free(cpu_s);

    cudaFree(gpu_s);

    cudaFree(gpu_a);
    cudaFree(gpu_b); 

    return 0;

}        

void Init()
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < M; i++)

   cpu_s[i] = 0;
}
```

The result is:
[Smith@server]$ ./test88.exe
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

Comment: It's always a good idea to do [cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) on every cuda call (cudaMemcpy, cudaMalloc, kernel calls, etc.)  Your kernel gives a launch failure.

Answer (score 2):

Your code tries to reach beyond the array length - gpu_s length is 6 * sizeof(float) while tid can be up to 900*900.

Setting P to 6 prints out:
-3.000000 -3.000000 5.000000 -3.000000 5.000000 -3.000000

Note - you can easily detect such problems by running your application with [cuda-memcheck](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html).